# Ignore nested quote marks with RegEx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I need to write a regular expression that will get me the text between 2 quote marks, but I need it to only match the first and last quote marks in a string.

For instance;

> "Please press "Yes" if you wish to proceed"

Needs to read;

> Please press "Yes" if you wish to proceed

The RegEx im currently using is this;

```
 ([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

Which, with the above example would bring back the match

> Please press

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just crop out the first and last characters?

Comment: It's for a resource file and needs to be split by regex. So the file might look like name = "resource" or name = "res"thing"ource". I need to use a regex to get the relevant text.

Comment: You can just use [IndexOf/LastIndexOf and Substring](http://ideone.com/wwTgpW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
(?!["]).*(?<!["])
```

Comment: That's the one! Could you please explain which part is allowing the nested quotes to be ignored? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. The original regex is basically: ["](.*)["] This regex matches between only first and last quotes; but matching with quotes. I mean the result was: "Please press "Yes" if you wish to proceed" .So I added additional look ahead "?!" and look behind "?<!" parameters for trim the quotes.

Comment: I would not recommend using lookarounds here. Use `(?s)"(.*)"` and get the `match.Groups[1].Value`.